# What is the XPATH of following web element?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to find the XPATH of the following element. I want to click on 'Next' hyperlink. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  <span class="inputtextfields"> &lt;Previous&nbsp; <a accesskey="n" href="javascript:ButtonClickFunction('NEXT' , 1, 'bulkpayments.jsp')">Next</a>&gt; </span>
```

Comment: Accepting someone's answer and then removing it is not a good practice bro. If you were not satisfied with my answer , you should have not ticked it earlier only.

Comment: Hello Kishan, I have upvoted your answer bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these below mentioned code.

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[text()='Next']")).click();
```

**Explanation:-** Use `text` method along with `<a>` tag.

> OR

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[@accesskey='n']").click();
```

**Explanation:-** Use `accesskey` attribute with `<a>` tag.

> OR

```
 driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[@accesskey='n'][text()='Next']").click();
```

**Explanation:-** Use `accesskey` attribute and `text` method along with `<a>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I accepted the answer. Please vote to the question

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Xpaths:

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[@accesskey='n']").click();

driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Next')]").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use link text `"Next"` to match required element:

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[text()='Next']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(by.linkText("Next")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

the xpath should be "//a[contains(.,'Next')]"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XPath:

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//span[@class='inputtextfields']").click();
```